# Intel virtualization technology keeps disabling automatically

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, bios

I am trying to use virtual box in ubuntu. And I am stuck here, were I have to enable Intel Virtualization Technology. I go to BIOS then enable it, I save changes till then, it is still enable. Then when I turn on my Lenovo G40-70 Laptop to use virtual box. It is already disabled. How do i make it stable. Are there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please mention which version of Ubuntu you're running? For now, I'm going to assume that you're using Ubuntu 17.10. If that is the case, then the problem could be due to this reason : [Ubuntu 17.10 Breaks the BIOS on Some Lenovo Laptops](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios)

Apparently, Ubuntu 17.10 is breaking the BIOS on some Lenovo laptops, and because of this, any changes made in BIOS settings (in your case, enabling virtualization) don't get saved. Seeing that your laptop is a Lenovo, (and assuming that you're running 17.10), I think this may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes It is 17.10. And I think I should do as per that webpage said "In the meantime the best thing for all Linux-loving Lenovo users to do is wait. For more details, workarounds, and irate feedback check out the bug report." Thank you this was Helpful.

Comment: @Iamrub3n You're welcome. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of BIOS settings that can't be stored is usually caused by dead CMOS battery (battery on the motherboard). If the CMOS battery is dead, there is no power in the motherboard to store the BIOS settings. Did you check that in the first place?

Comment: But i think date and time is always adjusted. How is that possible if CMOS battery was dead.

Comment: @lamrub3n On Ubuntu, that can happen through [NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html) (getting the time from the Internet).

Comment: @Caramello To complete-comment on Caramello's solution, yes, it is a new issue known for some weeks, and the affected lenovo models can be found here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147 . Your G40-70 is NOT currently on the list but it is very possible that it could be affected too. If you checked the general solution (battery), you should point in direction of the (very serious issue) stated by Caramello.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I don't think my CMOS battery is dead because i have not enabled date and time adjustment through Internet till now. There is option but it is disabled.